# Indicating lists with common free variables in SWI Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need help for a predicate I need to implement in a project. It looks like this:

```erlang
mypredicate( ListOfLists, List1, Result)
```

Basically, Result is the list of members of `ListOfLists` which have at least one variable in common with `List1`.

The problem I'm having is that `List1` and the elements of `ListOfLists` are lists of free variables.

An example of what it's supposed to do:

```erlang
List1 = [A,B,C],
ListOfLists = [[A,G,D],[E,J,X,T],[A,C,M],[F,K,L,J,R]],
mypredicate( ListOfLists, List1, Result).
% ==>
Result = [[A,G,D],[A,C,M]];
false.
```

I've been stuck on this for so much time, and I can't seem to get it right. This was my closest attempt (I think):

```erlang
% Similar to the predefined member/2, but changed to work with free variables.

member_wout_unify(_, []) :- fail.
member_wout_unify( El, List) :- List = [P | R], (P == El ;
    member_wout_unify( El, R)).

% common_elements(List1, List2) is true if there is at least 
%   one element which appears in both lists.
% Works with free variables.

common_elements([], _) :- fail.
common_elements([El | _ ], List2) :- member_wout_unify(El, List2).
common_elements([ _ | R ], List2) :- common_elements(R, List2).

mypredicate( ListOfLists, List1, Result) :-
        bagof( Member_ListOfLists,
               ( member_wout_unify( Member_ListOfLists, ListOfLists),
                 common_elements( List1, Member_ListOfLists) ),
               Result).
```

This predicate returns `false.` even when it's not supposed to.

I've tried using `findall/3` instead of `bagof/3`, but it always responds with `Result = []`.

I'd appreciate any help I could get, thanks in advance.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need clauses, `member_wout_unify(_,[]) :- fail.` or `common_elements([],_) :- fail.` as they are superfluous. Those cases will automatically fail when there is no clause in which they succeed.

Comment: You can test your program in pieces. Play with `member_wout_unify` at the prolog prompt. You'll find that it's not working as expected. You need unification when using your member function to generate members in your `bagof`. So use `member` in your `bagof`, but keep using `member_wout_unify` in your `common_elements` predicate.

Comment: @lurker Thank you very much! This was the solution.